# How to download to the browser multiple pictures in php

Tags: php

I'm getting some pictures paths via a webservice this way :

```
 0 => string '/home/41/38/58/96/photos/1.jpg' 
 1 => string '/home/41/38/58/96/photos/2.jpg'
 2 => string '/home/41/38/58/96/photos/3.jpg'
```

I'm trying to download them to the browser via a PHP script :

```
foreach($files as $index => $files){
        if($index !== 'debug'){
            $file_name = basename($file);
            $final_file = @fopen($file,"rb");

            header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            header("Pragma: public");
            header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"");
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

            header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));

            print(@fread($final_file, filesize($file)));
            ob_flush();
            flush();

            @fclose($final_file);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that i'm getting just one picture even if my array contains the three links like you see. So what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: If Javascript is available to you then you can look into [dynamically creating `<iframe>`s which will initiate an individual download of each file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9425731/2191572)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can send just one file.

You need to [zip](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) the files into one archive and then send that zip file to the browser.

there are some [other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047645/download-multiple-files-without-using-zip-file), but zipping should be good for most cases imho